# A number to the group cardinality power

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Well my question is how is possible this:

Consider an element $g\in G$, where $G$ is a finite group, then you have:

$g^{|G|}=e$

How can I prove it?

Thank you.

Comment: What can you say about the subgroups of $G$, and their order in relation to $|G|$ ?

Comment: Have you thought of what happens if you're looking at $g, g^2, \dots, g^n$ etc., and $g^{|G|}$ is not yet $e$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's mostly an intuition kind of thing. Are you family with Lagrange's theorem for groups and sub groups? It says the subgroup order must divide the group order. We can use this idea to prove it intuitively.

For example a group $ G $ with $ n $ elements such that an element $ a \in G $. Let's now consider the sub group of order $ m $ generated by $ a $ cyclically $<a> $. Thus $ a^m=e $ and $ m $ must divide $ n $, so $a^n=e $. This is true for all elements of $ G $.

Comment: Wel is an introduction to abstract algebra thank you @dylan7 I did not know that I could prove it like you did :) I thought I had to do the product by hand :)

Comment: @user162343 You're welcome. There are probably more formal proofs you can find. I personally like looking at the intuition behind things. Saying a theorem is true just because it makes sense. And lagrange's theorem is very intuitive too.

Comment: I had to do this same problem recently, but I was not allowed to use Lagrange to do it. Even so, this answer helps quite a bit. Essentially, if you don't have what you want to prove then two distinct elements must be the same which is nonsensical. Caylay tables help too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)), with $H=<g>$

Answer (score 1):

This is the corollary of Lagrange's theorem in Gallian's book. $\text{ord}(g)$ divides $\text{ord}(G)$ then $\text{ord}(G)=k \cdot \text{ord}(g)$. Now $a^{\text{ord}(G)}=e$.